# Merging dataframes into dataframe format by matching rows AND columns

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, matching

Recently I have started using R again. I am having problems with the following problem:

I have created a dataframe format in which I want to merge smaller dataframes into, based on both the columns and rows. I want to keep the dimensions of the large format dataframe and insert the data of the smaller dataframes. The tables that I am working with are quite big, but I have created some example data.

The large dataframe, which is an empty format table:

```
formattable <- data.frame("Agriculture" = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),"Mining" = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                "Industry" = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),"Services" = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), "Households" = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
                row.names = c("N01 water","N02 solar", "P01 coal", "P02 natural gas", "P03 diesel", "R01 waste", "R02 residuals","R03 losses" ) )
```

The smaller dataframes that hold data:

```
data1 <- data.frame("Agriculture" = c(5,7,NA),"Mining" = c(5,6,NA),
                 "Services" = c(4,8,NA), "Households" = c(1,11,NA), 
                 row.names = c("P01 coal", "P02 natural gas", "P03 diesel") )

data2 <- data.frame("Agriculture" = c(3,2),"Mining" = c(NA,5)
                          ,"Services" = c(5,7), 
                          row.names = c("N01 water","N02 solar") )

data3 <- data.frame("Agriculture" = c(3,6,5),"Mining" = c(NA,0,5),
                          "Industry" = c(5,NA,NA),"Services" = c(NA,NA,NA), "Households" = c(7,8,9), 
                          row.names = c("R01 waste", "R02 residuals","R03 losses" ) )
```

As an end product, I want one large dataframe that holds all the data from the smaller dataframes. The combinations of rows and columns that are empty/zero should still be visible with the value "0". Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this one with `tidyverse` functions:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

formattable  |>
    rownames_to_column()  |> 
    rows_patch(rownames_to_column(data1), by = "rowname")  |>
    rows_patch(rownames_to_column(data2), by = "rowname")  |>
    rows_patch(rownames_to_column(data3), by = "rowname")  |>
    mutate(across(
        Agriculture:Households, \(col) replace_na(col, 0)
        )
    ) |> 
    column_to_rownames()

#                 Agriculture Mining Industry Services Households
# N01 water                 3      0        0        5          0
# N02 solar                 2      5        0        7          0
# P01 coal                  5      5        0        4          1
# P02 natural gas           7      6        0        8         11
# P03 diesel                0      0        0        0          0
# R01 waste                 3      0        5        0          7
# R02 residuals             6      0        0        0          8
# R03 losses                5      5        0        0          9
```

**EDIT: Using Reduce**

If you are using more than three data frames to update the original, you might want to put them in a `list` and use `Reduce` to avoid having to repeat yourself:

```r
# Note use of `rownames_to_column()` on first data frame
l  <- list(rownames_to_column(formattable), data1, data2, data3)

Reduce(\(x, y) rows_patch(
    x, 
    rownames_to_column(y), 
    by = "rowname"), 
    l)  |>
    mutate(across(
        Agriculture:Households, \(col) replace_na(col, 0)
        )
    ) |> 
    column_to_rownames()

#                 Agriculture Mining Industry Services Households
# N01 water                 3      0        0        5          0
# N02 solar                 2      5        0        7          0
# P01 coal                  5      5        0        4          1
# P02 natural gas           7      6        0        8         11
# P03 diesel                0      0        0        0          0
# R01 waste                 3      0        5        0          7
# R02 residuals             6      0        0        0          8
# R03 losses                5      5        0        0          9
```

You will need at least `dplyr v.1.0.0` for `rows_patch()`. From the [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html):

> rows_update() modifies existing rows (like UPDATE). Key values in y
> must be unique, and, by default, key values in y must exist in x.
>
> rows_patch() works like rows_update() but only overwrites NA values.

Comment: Thank you for your effort SamR, i appreciate it. I do get all kinds of errors when I work with my example data above. I checked and I am working with dplyr v1.0.3. Should be okay..
The first error that I get is: Error: unexpected input in "Reduce(\"

Comment: Are you using R >= v4.1? If not you need to upgrade, or replace the line `Reduce(\(x, y) rows_patch(` with `Reduce(function(x, y) rows_patch(`

Comment: I checked and its R 4.0.3 (64 bit). I have changed it to 4.1 and it works! Thanks so much. I can try with my real data now.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could potentially be to skip the larger data frame and use `bind_rows` and `replace_na` on the smaller:

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(data1, data2, data3) |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(., 0)))
```

Output:

```r
                Agriculture Mining Services Households Industry
P01 coal                  5      5        4          1        0
P02 natural gas           7      6        8         11        0
P03 diesel                0      0        0          0        0
N01 water                 3      0        5          0        0
N02 solar                 2      5        7          0        0
R01 waste                 3      0        0          7        5
R02 residuals             6      0        0          8        0
R03 losses                5      5        0          9        0
```

**Update: The *long* approach**

To offer yet another alternative approach, it might come (very) handy for you to work in longer formats instead until the very end.

In the example below I make the formattable redundant by using `expandgrid` (you could use `pivot_longer` on your current table too) and you could update the values by a doing a simple join (or use an **experimental** `rows_*`-function, here `rows_update`). As you might have guessed from SamR's answer rownames are not the best for these tasks, so I'll keep them as an ID instead of using `column_to_rownames()`.

```r
expand.grid(ID = c("N01 water","N02 solar", "P01 coal", "P02 natural gas", "P03 diesel", "R01 waste", "R02 residuals","R03 losses"),
            name = c("Agriculture", "Mining", "Services", "Households", "Industry")) |>
  left_join(bind_rows(data1 |> rownames_to_column("ID") |> pivot_longer(-ID), 
                      data2 |> rownames_to_column("ID") |> pivot_longer(-ID),
                      data3 |> rownames_to_column("ID") |> pivot_longer(-ID))) |>
  mutate(value = replace_na(value, 0)) |>
  pivot_wider(ID)
```

That being said, what is smart will depend on your real data.

Comment: Yes I'd assumed from the way the question was phrased that there are additional rows or columns that need to be kept - hence the original dataframe - but if that is not the case then this is the simpler and better approach.

Comment: This works, but SamR is right. The format that I made is there to keep rows and columns that need to be kept eventhough there is no data. The dimensions need to be exactly the same every time.

Comment: When that the purpose of the format table, it might by handier for you too keep your data in a long format until the end. See update and good luck!

Comment: The format table is useless probably, in the example it is used just to sort the rownames, which can be done with `merged <- bind_rows(data1, data2, data3)
merged[order(rownames(merged)),]` and even if the order of columns need to be "formatted", you can just set/change the order of columns after the rbind